# Add textfield outlet collection together

Tags: ios, swift, logging, iboutletcollection

I want to print the total of all of the textfields connected to cool textfield collection. There are only 2, in the log file.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var cool: [UITextField]!

    @IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
        for view in cool {
   ((cool.text! as NSString).integerValue +=  ((cool.text! as NSString).integerValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need help with here? What issue are you having?

Comment: @rmaddy I have 2 textfields link to the outlet collection var cool. I just wanted to print the sum of both textfields linked to the var cool in the log section.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I'm asking what do you need help with? You have a loop. Have you done any research on how to convert the text field's text to an number?

Comment: @rmaddy I know how to do this with individual textfields by converting them to ints but I just have never used a outlet collection before to do this.

Comment: You already posted the needed loop. Inside the loop you have just one textfield and you just stated you know how to get its value. Just put the pieces together. Try something and update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried something similar with what I would use when adding 2 textfields separately together. This does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add up all of the text fields, then simply do:

```
@IBAction func press(_ sender: Any) {
    var total = 0
    for view in cool {
        if let text = view.text, let num = Int(text) {
            total += num
        }
    }

    print("The total is \(total)")
}
```

Don't force unwrap optionals. Don't use `NSString` in Swift.